# How to create a byte[] image intent to share with Email

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a `byte[]` image intent to share with the email app on my Xamarin.Android application. So far I have the following:

```
public void ShareAsync(byte[] image, string message)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) || image == null)
        return;

    var sharingIntent = new Intent();
    sharingIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
    sharingIntent.SetType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, image);
    sharingIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingIntent, message));
}
```

This pops up the share dialog and I can click the email app but it returns a blank email.

Is it possible to share a `byte[]` with the email app so that the image appears as part of the body or an attachment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the email app if it will accept the image as a byte array, which I'm sure won't work for most part of email apps for the reason of that you can't put a lot of data in the intent. It's size is limited to **1 MB** of data, so you won't be able to pass byte array larger than 1 MB in any case, even if the email app supported this type of image sharing.

So the short answer is that *there is no way*.

Comment: This does sound like the behavior I am seeing. I have seen other solutions passing a uri as an attachment. Does that sound like a more viable solution?

Comment: @user1, sure, passing the uri (of the image file) will work, and is a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly pass file uri in intent 
try this

```
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/*");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_text));
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_subject));

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("file:///" + "your image path"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting by this

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

`bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object`
`byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();`

and convert back to image like this

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

I have't tested it so let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(IMAGE URI));
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                translate.bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
            }

            bitmap.Dispose();
```